# Vue: Form listens to any event not just submit

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a form which basically looks like this:

```
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmitted">
  Email<input type="email" /> <br />Content<input type="text" />
  <CancelSave @cancel="onCanceled" />
</form>
```

There are input fields for an email and content and there is a custom component which emits `submit` and `cancel` events. I want the submit event to be automatically caught by the form and not by the button group.

Note that I explicitly want to use the html `<form>` element to get the features of html validation which I can't have (without any validation libraries at least) if i just wrap all the inputs in a div and listen to the submit or cancel events.

All works fine except that when I press `cancel` it is also caught as a submit and the form gets submitted.

Here's a sample of my code:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/62lo86rprr

**EDIT:** FYI Apparently when pressing the `cancel` button, cancel AND submit are caught

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cancel button in your form does not have a `type` attribute. By default, buttons within forms are assumed to be of type `submit`. Add a `type="reset"` to the cancel button to avoid the submission.

See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)